# Cancelling from Facebook permission authorization results in Android app force close

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, android-app, facebook

I have Facebook attached to my Stack Exchange account as well as Google. When I select to login via Facebook from the login screen, then cancel out of the "Stack Exchange Android App will receive the following info..." screen, the Android app will force close.

Steps to reproduce on v0.1.47:

1. Log out if needed
2. Select login via Facebook
3. When presented "Stack Exchange Android App will receive the following info..." screen, cancel.
4. Force close

I'm not on the up and up about Facebook authentication flows these days, but could it be possible that the Stack Exchange Android app shares the same Facebook app as the desktop site? It seems weird that I have to authorize two Stack Exchange Facebook apps to access my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report.

As of version 0.1.49 this will be correctly handled.

In regards to having to double authenticate, later down the line we might switch over to the main Facebook application id for android authorization but for now I don't think uniting them would give us anything extra. The actual app release would be a good time to switch it over if we're going to, I think.